# Checking amount of checked inputs on page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JS that when selecting a certain amount of items will disable the other options and while selecting those items will update the count which works great however! I'm at the point when I add these to a cart, and in the cart I can edit so when I click edit it comes back to the product page and I have the options selected that were selected by the customer when adding to the cart but my count shows 0 of 3 and the other options are not disabled.

I know I would need to do a each / foreach on page load to check if any checkboxes are checked and if so and at limit disable others etc, but it took me a while. I would like some assistance to get it to where it is in this Fiddle. How can I check for these on load?

Original Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ate9a04u/2/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxAllowed = 3;
  $(".rmax").html(maxAllowed);

  $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox").change(function() {
    var checkBox = $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox")
    var cnt = $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox:checked").length;
    if (cnt == maxAllowed) {
      checkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      checkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
    }

    $(".rcount").html(cnt);
  });
});
```

Comment: Added a checkboxes already checked here: https://jsfiddle.net/ate9a04u/4/ - 1 checkbox out of 3 just needs to update count value and https://jsfiddle.net/ate9a04u/5/ has 3 default selected so should say 3 of 3 and disable others until one deselected. thanks in advanced guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're saying you want the same processing that the `.change()` handler does to run not just when a checkbox is clicked but also on page load.

If so, just manually trigger the `.change()` handler yourself once right after binding it in your existing ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxAllowed = 3;
  $(".rmax").html(maxAllowed);

  $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox").change(function() {
    var checkBox = $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox")
    var cnt = $(".subscribtion-content input.checkbox:checked").length;
    if (cnt == maxAllowed) {
      checkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      checkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
    }

    $(".rcount").html(cnt);
  }).change();  // <--- this is all you need to add
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ate9a04u/6/

Comment: wow that was incredibly simple! i started a moment ago writing a each loop and well... did not even need to! thanks mate! ill remember that one :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can make the function a bit shorter without losing any readability - the following version avoids repeating that `".subscribtion-content input.checkbox"` selector and dispenses with the if/else: https://jsfiddle.net/ate9a04u/7/